# Puxar variável de um arquivo.js para outro aquivo.js ( Javascript )

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde, pessoal, estou criando um bot para WhatsApp e preciso fazer uma CRUD, porém gostaria de fazer de uma maneira organizada, então pensei se tivesse como puxar variável global.

Minha ideia seria:

No arquivo App.js tem 200 linhas, em umas dessas linha eu defino a variável por exemplo:

`const cliente = "Fernando"`

E então eu pego essa variável cliente, e consigo usar em outro aquivo, um arquivo chamado Crud.js.

Porém o problema é, se eu usar o `module.exports` eu importo todo o arquivo App.js desdá linha `0` até a `200` sendo que eu quero importar somente a variável `const cliente = "Fernando"`

Preciso saber como importa só a variável, sem nenhuma linha a mais, pois então eu usaria essa mesma variável em outros arquivos .js

Answer (score -1):

> Porém o problema é, se eu usar o `module.exports` eu importo todo o arquivo App.js desdá linha 0 até a 200 sendo que eu quero importar somente a variável `const cliente = "Fernando"`

Não necessariamente, se você apenas exportar a variável, já funcionará perfeitamente, basta importar no arquivo que queira, por exemplo:

Para exportar:

```
module.exports = cliente
```

E importar em outro arquivo, no caso, o Crud.js

```
const cliente = require("./App.js")
```

Assim, você poderá usar cliente, que no caso é Fernando, no arquivo Crud.js

Lembre-se, caso queira exportar mais variáveis, sugiro colocar dentro de um objeto e depois fazer o destruction, como por exemplo:

Para exportar:

```
module.exports = {
   cliente,
   status
}
```

E importar em outro arquivo, no caso, o Crud.js

```
const { cliente, status } = require("./App.js")
```

Sugiro esses artigos para você se aprofundar:

Module.exports: https://www.alura.com.br/artigos/utilizando-export-modules-no-node-js

Destruction: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Então infelizmente não funcionou, fiz o seguinte código:

teste1.js

```console.log("Eu sou o teste 1")

const cliente = "Fernando"

module.exports = cliente```

teste2.js

```const { cliente } = require("./teste1.js")


console.log(cliente)```

Infelizmente quando executo o teste2, ele puxa tudo, não puxa somente a variável...